# Dynamically switch file in get_template_directory_uri() | Function

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, themes, theme-options

I need to switch scheme color of my WordPress theme trough Redux option panel.

My plan is switch the CSS file trough get_template_directory_uri() | Function.

The scenario is:

1. Create 2 scheme color: dark and light with dark.css and libght.css.
2. Control from redux panel with this code:

   ```
   <?php
   Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'  => __( 'Color Scheme', 'javapaper' ),
    'id'     => 'test_scheme',
    'icon'   => 'el el-list',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'color_scheme',
            'type'     => 'image_select',
            'title'    => __( 'SELECT Color Scheme', 'javapaper' ),
            'subtitle' => __( '2 scheme Available', 'javapaper' ),              
            'options'  => array(
                'dark' => array(
                    'title' => 'dark',
                    'alt' => 'dark',
                    'img' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/header-styledefault.png'
                ),              
                'light' => array(
                    'title' => 'light',                 
                    'alt' => 'light',
                    'img' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/header-style2.png'
                )                   
            ),

            'default'  => 'dark'
        ),          

         )
     ) );
   ?>
   ```
3. Call the code from Redux panel into get_template_directory_uri() | Function like this:

   ```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'javapaper-lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/$redux_demo["color_scheme"]' );
   ```

But Unfortunately It did not work. I am newbie on php. Please help.

Comment: You should direct this question to Redux's official support channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that `$redux_demo["color_scheme"]` is getting the corresponding value, so your code should be:

```
global $redux_demo;
wp_enqueue_style( 'javapaper-lightbox-style', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/{$redux_demo['color_scheme']}.css" );
```

Assuming that you have files in this structure `css/dark.css` and `css/light.css`.

Comment: Unfortunately I got this warning :Notice: Undefined variable: redux_demo in F:\xamppupdate\wp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\javapaper\functions.php on line 72

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in F:\xamppupdate\wp\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\javapaper\functions.php on line 72

Comment: The HTL output:
<link rel='stylesheet' id='javapaper-lightbox-style-css'  href='http://127.0.0.1:81/wordpress/wp-content/themes/javapaper/css/.css?ver=5.9.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
I need to insert the text as the name of the css, in my case dark.css and light.css.

Comment: May be you have to add the `global $redux_demo;`. Please check the edit

Comment: It's coresponding to text "dark" and "light", the output I need "dark.css" or "light.css"

Comment: Yes and that is the main problem that you are trying to access a value stored in `$redux_demo` which is not defined. So while redux stores options inside the `global $redux_demo;` you should add it before the line you want to use within or at you function beginning.

Comment: Thank you. It's work. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Glad i could help.